# Is it possible to call a function every time a view is updated in Durandal?

Tags: jquery, durandal

I have a web application using Durandal and I want to call

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.selectpicker').selectPicker();
}
```

every time a view is updated. 
Does anyone have any suggestions of how to go about this?

Comment: you have typo  `$('document)` change this to  `$(document)`

Comment: Ah yeah that was just me typing it into here wrong!

Comment: What do you mean with "updated"?

Comment: Is updating a view firing an event? (i ask it because i don't know durandal)

Comment: Anyway, I recommend you to use custom bindings for all the stuff related to UI customizations ( date pickers, autocomplete inputs.. ): http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/custom-bindings.html

Answer (score 0):

With durandal, you don't need to use jQuery's document ready event.  Simply put this into your view model's attached event, and expose that event to the view...

```
define([], function () {

var attached = function (view) {
    $('.selectpicker').selectPicker();        
};

var vm = {
    attached: attached;
};

return vm;

});
```

This will fire what you want when the DOM is ready (aka the view is attached) if you are using Durandal's router.  As mentioned in the comments, to make this even better you can move all DOM manipulation into a custom binding handler and promote code re-use and readability.